# Ajax or SignalR for order screen

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, signalr

Currently I have an application in which a user stares at a dashboard, the dashboard will display new orders coming in for that user. I have rolled out the application for testing and most users are complaining of time delays and crahsing.

Currently I am using `jQuery` and Ajax using `setInterval()` and then an `Ajax` call to get the orders and update the screen every 30 seconds. However in some instances where there are a lot of orders the `Ajax` calls become overlapped.

I have stumbled across a new technology to me which seems like the solution `SignalR` but I have looked at the examples and have not seen any comments on performance.

Question - What is the performance like and would it be a better solution to the current above, also is it possible to configure this to target only a specific user and can this be done to the current logged in user's ID? I am using MVC4.

Any comments would be appreciated,

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use SignalR to send messages to a specific client/user. Take a look at the documentation here to find out more about this: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki. SignalR allows you to make remote procedure calls (RPC's) from the client and the server and you should be able to push any notifications/new orders to the client almost immediately.

There aren't any published performance metrics for SignalR as yet but you can test it out to see how efficiently your traffic is handled.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I cant see where the documents say how I can allocate a userID to a clientID?

Comment: You would have to maintain a data structure on the Hub to map the connection id's to user id's. SignalR merely provides you the connection id, you have to handle the rest of the logic.